# How to disable automatically generated fields in Python Eve?

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, eve

How to disable fields `_updated`, `_created`, `_etag`, `_links`? 
I want to limit bandwidth and those fields are bigger size than data which I actually need to get from my database (Mongodb)

Comment: Take a look at http://python-eve.org/config.html#projection

Answer (score 8):

With the exceptions of `_links`, which you can remove by disabling HATEOAS (`HATEOAS = False`), you can only rename the other meta fields.

While the framework itself won't remove them, you could hook up a custom callback and purge those fields yourself before the response is sent over the wire.

```
from eve import Eve

def on_fetched_resource(resource, response):
    for document in response['_items']:
        del(document['_etag'])
        # etc.

app = Eve()
app.on_fetched_resource += on_fetched_resource

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: I have the same issue, but the proposed solution doesn't fit my case: 
I have an existing MysqlDB schema that I cannot change, and I want to use eve-sqlalchemy. So the framework fails on POST PUT requests because there are mo _updated and _created columns...

Answer (score 0):

**Good question!**

If you not too anxious about concurrency control which is for the user-side integrity, you can disable it, and so the `_etag` field. This can be done by adding a simple option in your `settings.py`:

```
IF_MATCH = False
```

This also may be handy if you want to edit database with an external tools or apps, as it lets you avoid doing additional *jiggery-pokery* with "_etag".

To understand whether you need ETag, check out: https://docs.python-eve.org/en/stable/features.html#data-integrity-and-concurrency-control

Also refer to [Nicola Iarocci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/323269/nicola-iarocci), who mentioned about disabling HATEOAS (`HATEOAS = False`) and a way to remove `_etag` field without disabling ETag checks. *(Actually I wonder how you can check and post with latest `_etag` then?)*